# Django How to display a link from user input form safely

Tags: html, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I have an model (posts) that is tied to a form that when a certain character is used it creates a link to another portion of the web app. The user can enter several of these characters/links to different areas of the webpage in one post then I want to display all of the users posts to the user in a list looping over the model that stores the link. However, how can I do this while maintaining security? I do not want to allow the user to enter in HTML and it be rendered.

For example:

1. User enters form information:

"Hello this is a @test and @about is a test too"

2. User selects submit button and background magic to get the words **test** and **about** and convert them into links to take the user to the test and about pages in the web application.
3. Display all of the inputs/posts that have been created:

"Hello this is a [@test](https://stackoverflow.com) and [@about](https://stackoverflow.com) is a test too"

I know that I can use the `safe` tag and just store the HTML link in the model and call like normal but since this is from user input I don't want to allow them to create HTML inside of the input form. How can I achieve this desired result safely?

Loosely what I have now:
views.py

```py
def index(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        post_form = PostForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if post_form.is_valid():
            # TODO Add background magic here
            post_form.save()
            messages.success(request, ('Your post was successfully added!'))
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'Error saving form')
        return redirect("/posts")
    
    post_form = PostForm()
    posts = Post.objects.all()

    return render(request=request, template_name="posts/page.html", context={'post_form':post_form, 'posts':posts})
```

page.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Testing</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
            {{ post_form }}
            <button class="btn btn-primary my-4" type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
      {% for post in posts %}
      <p>{{post.id}}</p>
      <p>{{post.post}}</p>
      {% endfor %}
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If the user types in at-tests and at-posts, what part of that is the link? You say there is "background magic" involved in converting them to <a> tags with links, where do those links come from? Are they stored somewhere? or does the user provide them somehow?

Comment: @MarkBarrett The links are just to other pages inside of the webapplication, so the 'background magic' I refer to is just filtering the post to find where the at symbol is then matching the word associated with the pages and returning the link to that page mentioned. So the user never inputs a link, they are predetermined and only keywords will be linked to the pages.

Comment: Ah I see, so the only thing you are worried about is if the input field the user types into has HTML etc in it?

Comment: @MarkBarrett Exactly. I am trying to figure out how to display their posts with the link included back to them in a safe way.

Comment: If that’s the case then the links are fine as you store them yourself. As for the input, I feel all you have to worry about is if it’s sanitised, which you can do with multiple Python built ins or libraries

Comment: @MarkBarrett But where do I try and sanitize it? I have tried before saving, I have tried after saving and updating the model but everytime that I have the `safe` attribute in the template I still get all HTML

Comment: Are you saving the input to the model yes? If you are, that will sanitise it regardless. In terms of using the safe attribute, what is the use case to doing that? Are you saving HTML for those links in the DB? Are you the only person saving HTML?